# Sort array using php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Trying to understand how to sort the following array based on the value. Tried the regular functions for sort, asort, ksort etc like:

sort($array) but no luck. Any thoughts?

```
   Array
   (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [text] => 2015-01-01 - 2015-12-31
            [value] => 2015-01-01
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [text] => 2018-01-01 - 2018-12-31
            [value] => 2018-01-01
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [text] => 2017-01-01 - 2017-12-31
            [value] => 2017-01-01
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [text] => 2014-01-01 - 2014-12-31
            [value] => 2014-01-01
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [text] => 2013-01-01 - 2013-12-31
            [value] => 2013-01-01
        )
    
)
```

Comment: I believe you need to use `usort` with your own comparison function (or maybe `uasort`): https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: Use `usort` and in your comparator function just use `return strcmp($a['value'], $b['value']);`